# Need to change UID and Password for linked table to Pervasive database

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

So, I inherited support for an MSAccess 2016 database that includes a table that is linked to either a table or view in a Pervasive (Btrieve?) database.  The problem is that the link was established by a developer using his personal credentials, and he is no longer with the company.  Further, the "ForeignName" field in MSysObjects for the linked table does not appear to match any table or view I have been able to find in the Pervasive database.  I'm also suspicious that the Connect field in MSysObjects for this linked table is exactly 255 characters - I suspect that there's more data stored in the Connect field than I'm actually able to retrieve.  I need to be sure that I have all of the information necessary to re-link the table so the former employee's account can be disabled without disrupting business operations.

Below are the values I'm seeing from MSysObjects (scrubbed for security reasons)

Connect
DSN=Timberline Data Source;DatabaseType=1;DBQ=\SERVER1\Timberline Office\Data\Company Name12\;DictionaryMode=0;Driver={C:\Program Files (x86)\Timberline Office\Shared\tssimba.dll};MaxColSupport=255;PWD=password;ShortenNames=0;StandardMode=0;UID=dev12345;

ForeignName
NINA_PRT_TIME

Name
NINA_PRT_TIME

I'm not an expert in Pervasive, but we have found neither a table nor a view named "NINA_PRT_TIME".  So, I suspect that there may be additional information in the Connect field that Access isn't showing me when the table is queried.  My question is:  how can I be sure I'm getting ALL of the data from the Connect field and it's not being truncated at 255 characters?

Comment: Does `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("linked table name").Connect` give you any additional information?

Comment: If you're using a DSN (which you apparently are), additional information might be stored in the DSN. I generally recommend going DSNless to keep the information in one place and have the database be portable.

Comment: @HansUp:  Tried that -- no additional information.